# Vue JS dynamic validation message gets disappered on navigating to other form fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using `Vue JS` with `Vue Validator`.

As per the project requirement I need some `server-side` validations to check **duplicate** entries.

For this, I put a `watcher` on `email_id` field, on change of the same an ajax request returns whether the provided email address is duplicate or not (`true` or `false`).

If `false` then I need to **set error dynamically** for the same.

Everything works fine but the problem is, ***the error message gets disappear automatically on blur of any field on the form***.

You may check my codes here : https://jsfiddle.net/m670da45/23/

Please let me know how to `prevent` hiding error message i.e. set dynamically?

**P.S.** For easy understanding, instead of using `ajax` request, I have set an `email` address "xyz@xyz.com". Insert given email address in `Email` field and navigate to `Alternate email` field, again navigating to `Email` field will hide the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom validator which returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) like this:

```
Vue.validator('exist', function (val, arg) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      if (val === 'xyz@xyz.com') {
        reject()
      } else {
        resolve()
      }
    }, 1000)
  })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pespantelis/m670da45/24/

For more details about the async validation, you could check the related section on Docs: http://vuejs.github.io/vue-validator/en/async.html

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thanks a lot with upvote.. I was having issue with Vue js version in my project. Updated to latest one along with validator js did the job.